Installing libpostal in Databricks
I am trying to install libpostal python wrapper in Databricks.
pip install postal ended up with

CalledProcessError: Command 'pip --disable-pip-version-check install
postal' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Do you have any suggestion on how to get libpostal running in Databricks?
Thank you.

try this py -m pip install pylibpostal

I found a way to run it:
install pylibpostal via Databricks cluster library.
Thereafter in notebook run the following code to download the required data and store it in storage accessible by Databricks. In my case it is an ADLS.
I use the data from senzing - Senzing /libpostal-data
# Download and unpack

%sh
# language classifier
curl -L https://public-read-libpostal-data.s3.amazonaws.com/v1.1.0/language_classifier.tar.gz | tar -xzvf - -C /dbfs/mnt/data/pylibpostal/

# Libpostal data
curl https://public-read-libpostal-data.s3.amazonaws.com/v1.1.0/libpostal_data.tar.gz | tar -xzvf - -C /dbfs/mnt/data/pylibpostal/

# Parser
curl https://public-read-libpostal-data.s3.amazonaws.com/v1.1.0/parser.tar.gz | tar -xzvf - -C /dbfs/mnt/data/pylibpostal/

You can create an init script to improve on the code above to check for new version etc.
import os 
os.environ['LIBPOSTAL_DATA_DIR'] = "/dbfs/mnt/data/pylibpostal/"
from pylibpostal.expand import expand_address
expand_address('Quatre vingt douze Ave des Champs-Élysées')


Out[14]: ['92 avenue des champs-elysees',
'92 avenue des champs elysees',
'92 avenue des champselysees']

